# "You'll see you're making less mistakes." or "You'll see you make less mistakes."

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I'm confused a bit. Which tense should I use after "will"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 parts to this question.

**Fewer / less:** It should be "fewer" when you're referring to a plural noun (like "Now I have fewer dollars") and "less" when you're reducing the amount of a single noun ("Now I have less money").

**Future tense** You can use either, but the second version is more direct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Caleb! What do you mean by "…is more direct"?

Answer (score 3):

"...less mistakes" should be "...fewer mistakes." as in:

"You'll see [that] you make fewer mistakes."